# Salesforce report

Tags: salesforce, reporting

I have created a report with standard report type - Campaigns with leads, there is filter added in the report to just display leads related to campaign which has lead stage as 'Meeting occurred', I have also added a bar graph to show the count of number of leads which has lead stage as 'meeting occurred' in a campaign.

[Full report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2RZy.png)

[Graph settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY2A7.png)

My question is how do I sort the bar graph and the details in descending order? please guide.